# Filehelpers reading data from external source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv, filehelpers

I am trying to read an external source CSV file with filehelpers.

**Here is my code:**

```
var engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<FileController>();

        using (engine.BeginReadFile("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xxxyyyzzz/data.csv"))
        {
            foreach(FileController csvData in engine)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(csvData.batteryLevel);
            }
        }
```

*engine.BeginReadFile* not working with http links. How can I read this file with Filehelpers?

Comment: Download the file first then use FileHelper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think FileHelpers works over http.  But you can download it first:

```
var engine = new FileHelperAsyncEngine<FileController>();

    string fileName = DownloadFile("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/xxxyyyzzz/data.csv");
    using (engine.BeginReadFile(fileName))
    {
        foreach(FileController csvData in engine)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(csvData.batteryLevel);
        }
    }
    File.Delete(fileName);


public static string DownloadFile(Uri url)
{
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n") + ".csv");
    WebClient aWebClient = new WebClient();
    aWebClient.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: You could potentially modify the source to use the stream from the request, but I think it would be best to keep them separate as per this example so that you can properly handle any web related issues, including retrying to get the data rather than parsing directly.  Plus if the connection is broken, you could end up with a partial read which might be more harmful than good depending on what you are doing with the data.